# How to add PostgreSQL driver (jar) to open-liberty microprofile fat jar created with liberty-maven-plugin?

Tags: java, postgresql, maven, jpa, open-liberty

I am trying to use PostgreSQL with my MicroProfile application but it failes to load the driver. My server.xml contains this:

```
<dataSource jndiName="jdbc/reports">
    <jdbcDriver libraryRef="PostgresLib" />
    <properties.postgresql serverName="localhost"
                           portNumber="5432"
                           databaseName="reports"
                           user="reports"
                           password="reports"/>
</dataSource>

<library id="PostgresLib">
    <fileset dir="${server.config.dir}/lib"
             includes="postgresql-42.2.9.jar"/>
</library>
```

I tried to copy the jar file via maven-dependency-plugin but there is not jar file in the target/liberty folder. I guess the liberty-maven-plugin clears the folders before. I also added the following dependency to my pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
    <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
    <version>42.2.9</version>
</dependency>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2):

The example configuration would be correct if the PostgreSQL jar were located at
`${server.config.dir}/lib/postgresql-42.2.9.jar`

However, it sounds like you are saying that the PostgreSQL jar is actually packaged within your application.  Currently, the only way to define a data source for a JDBC driver that is package within an application is to configure an application-defined data source (`@DataSourceDefinition` on a web or ejb component or `<data-source>` in a deployment descriptor), not in server configuration (the `dataSource` and `library` elements in your example).

For example, you could configure something like the following on a Servlet,

```
@DataSourceDefinition(name = "java:app/env/jdbc/reports",
                      className = "org.postgresql.xa.PGXADataSource",
                      databaseName = "reports",
                      serverName="localhost",
                      portNumber=5432,
                      user = "reports",
                      password = "reports")
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Resource(lookup = "java:app/env/jdbc/reports")
    DataSource reportsDataSource;
    ...
```

Comment: Is there a way to package it withing the fat jar though? So far I had no luck in getting any driver in the Open Liberty in the fatjar. Only inside the war file that gets deployed.

Answer (score 0):

This looks fine. All you have to do is to add the Postgres-Maven Dependency in your pom.xml and build your application using maven. This tells Maven to download the Postgres Library and add it to your classpath (there is no need to download and copy the library manually).

If you want to build a working jar file, you should use the maven [package](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) goal.

Comment: But how does the open-liberty finds the jar? My `library` declaration in the server.xml should be using the driver jar inside the fatjar of my application but outside of the war file inside the far jar. Adding the postgresql dependency to my project add it to the war file inside the fat jar, right? But how is open-liberty able to access that then?

Comment: My pom.xml looks like this: https://pastebin.com/Q0njnvii if that helps